# Как задать вводимый параметр в объект класса

Tags: c++, ооп

мне необходимо, чтобы в объект класса myclass можно было бы ввести вводимую с клавиатуры переменную n, которая является полем класса, но при таком вводе вылезает ошибка, что идентификатор n не определен, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myclass {
    public:
        int n;
};

int main()
{
    myclass obj;
    cin >> obj.n;
    myclass obj(n);
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте удалить строчку myclass obj(n);

Comment: Извиняюсь, не уточнил, после есть конструктор, в котором применяется n и он просит, чтобы в объекте obj был параметр

Comment: А зачем? Вы уже инициализировали obj и записали ввод в obj.n. Далее уже происходит что-то непонятное - попытка объявления переменной с уже занятым именем, с передачей несуществующей переменной n в несуществующий конструктор obj(int). Вам либо стоит лучше описать свой пример, либо удалить "myclass obj(n);" за ненадобностью и даже вредностью.